# How do I write an Angular directive to transform text to mark-up

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this template

```
<span highlight>{{player.Name}}</span>
```

and this directive

```
wcApp.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var nameStr = element.text();

            nameStr = $.map(nameStr,function(letter){
                return letter == ' ' ? '&#160;' : letter;
            });

            element.html('<span>' + nameStr.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
        }
    };
});
```

But it's not working. I want to grab the text in the span, break-up the letters and wrap each character in a span.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the binding, element haven't been compiled yet, there is diffrent way to solve this (prioritize you directive after compile, binding & compiling it yourself with the compileProvider)

```
wcApp.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var nameStr = element.text();

            alert(nameStr); // {{player.Name}}

            nameStr = $.map(nameStr,function(letter){
                return letter == ' ' ? '&#160;' : letter;
            });

            element.html('<span>' + nameStr.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
        }
    };
});
```

Alternative solution:

```
<span highlight="player.name"></span>
```

...and js

```
wcApp.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope: {highlight: "="},
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var nameStr = scope.highlight;

            // alert(nameStr); // not {{player.Name}}

            nameStr = $.map(nameStr,function(letter){
                return letter == ' ' ? '&#160;' : letter;
            });

            element.html('<span>' + nameStr.join('</span><span>') + '</span>');
        }
    };
});
```

simpulton have written a very good blog post about this worth reading:
http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.directive('highlight', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        template: '<span ng-repeat="l in letters">{{ l.letter }}</span>',
        link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var nameStr = attrs.highlight;
            nameStr = nameStr.split("");

            var map = [];
            var i=0, len=nameStr.length;
            for (; i<len; i++) {
                map.push({letter: nameStr[i] = nameStr[i].replace(" ", "&#160;")});
            }

            scope.letters = map;
        }
    };
});
```